# Is there a ColdFusion equivalent of phpinfo()

Tags: php, coldfusion

Is there a ColdFusion equivalent of phpinfo()? I don't know much about ColdFusion except that our university servers support it. I basically just want to know what version we are running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Checking The ColdFusion Version](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/140-Ask-Ben-Checking-The-ColdFusion-Version.htm):

> Checking your ColdFusion version could not be easier. All you have to do is dump out the SERVER scope. The version of ColdFusion is contained in a field titled "ColdFusion.ProductVersion." You should see a number like 7,0,1,116466. Additionally, the type license type of the system (ex. enterprise, developer, etc.) is in a field titled "ColdFusion.ProductLevel."

And there is also a code sample:

```
<!--- Dump out the server scope. --->
<cfdump var="#SERVER#" />

<!--- Store the ColdFusion version. --->
<cfset strVersion = SERVER.ColdFusion.ProductVersion />

<!--- Store the ColdFusion level. --->
<cfset strLevel = SERVER.ColdFusion.ProductLevel />
```

Comment: just like having an easy button.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @typoknig Hey did you know your name is spell.. oh, never mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your server's ColdFusion Administrator, this and more is also available under System Information. Log in and click white "i" in the blue circle in the upper right corner of the window.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to anything related to administration, and my university is just big enough that it is difficult to get a hold of the right people to get something simple like this taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

An easier method would be navigating to the ColdFusion administrator page

Http:///CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm

You would be able to see the version you are running in that screen.